# I don't know why I can't reach answer. (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c

I am a student just learned c&c++ a little. I want to print arData[3][4]. Also, I want to solve this question with only one 'for' phrase. (not to print, to make array) What could I have been wrong? Thanks for letting me know.

I want to print like this.
1 2  3  4
5 6  7  8
9 10 11 12

But print now
9 10 11 12
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0

```
int arData[3][4]{};
    int nData{};
    int nIndex1{};
    int nIndex2{};

    nData = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (0 < nData <= 4)
            nIndex1 = 0;
        else if (4 < nData <= 8)
            nIndex1 = 1;
        else if (8 < nData <= 12)
            nIndex1 = 2;

        if (nData % 4 == 1)
            nIndex2 = 0;
        else if (nData % 4 == 2)
            nIndex2 = 1;
        else if (nData % 4 == 3)
            nIndex2 = 2;
        else if (nData % 4 == 0)
            nIndex2 = 3;


        arData[nIndex1][nIndex2] = nData;
        nData++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", arData[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: A 2D array would want a nested for loop. For each row, for each column. And there's a formula you can figure out to know what value to assign if you want it to be [1, 12].

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Your code is valid C++, but not valid C, though it is written in C style.  My best advice to you right now is choose **one**.

Comment: `(0 < nData <= 4)` does not mean `0 < nData && nData <= 4` the way it does in, say, Python. In C++, this gets interpreted as `(0 < nData) <= 4`. That is, `(0 < nData)` is computed, then promoted into an int, then compared with `4`. Since a `bool` will only be `0` or `1` when promoted, this is actually just always true.

Comment: Pick a language; just one language.  If you want a solution in both languages state that, or post two questions.  The fragment you posted is appears to be compliable as C, so C++ is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0 < nData <= 4` is not a correct comparison in c++, you should do `0 < nData && nData <= 4`, where `&&` denotes logical AND operator. Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int arData[3][4]{};
    int nData{};
    int nIndex1{};
    int nIndex2{};

    nData = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (0 < nData  && nData <= 4)
            nIndex1 = 0;
        else if (4 < nData && nData <= 8)
            nIndex1 = 1;
        else if (8 < nData && nData <= 12)
            nIndex1 = 2;

        if (nData % 4 == 1)
            nIndex2 = 0;
        else if (nData % 4 == 2)
            nIndex2 = 1;
        else if (nData % 4 == 3)
            nIndex2 = 2;
        else if (nData % 4 == 0)
            nIndex2 = 3;


        arData[nIndex1][nIndex2] = nData;
        nData++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", arData[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Hi @ShinYoungJoen if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A stack-allocated two dimensional array will be laid out contiguously in memory, so you may as well initialize it like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int arData[3][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        (*arData)[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2d ", arData[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```